# AppleScript application can't get rights in Accessibility

Tags: macos, permissions, applescript

I'm having trouble with my own AppleScript applications and Accessibility in "Security & Privacy".

I've written an application called "open cubase" that I've granted accessibility rights. I used Apple's advice on how to prevent repeated re-authorization (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5914). But now even when the application is listed and selected in the Accessibility list, it says that it doesn't have assistive access.

[image: screenshot]

And when I'm using

```
sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/Tcc.db 'SELECT * FROM access WHERE client LIKE "%%"'
```

to check what's going on, I can see this:

```
kTCCServiceAccessibility|com.atonus.open-cubase|0|1|0|??
```

Why is there `??` at the end of that? Is there anyone who would know how to resolve this?

I'm using OSX 10.9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**, based on feedback from the OP:

- The OP's issue is *not* the use of `property` statements that normally cause an AppleScript-based application to self-modify the application bundle's embedded `Contents/Resources/Scripts/main.scpt` script file when property values change at runtime.
- However, Apple's workaround at http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5914

  - IS specifically meant to address not requiring re-authorization as a result of this self-modification issue for a *given version* of an application.
  - is NOT meant to allow *updating* the app (changing its source code or resources) without re-authorization.

**For security reasons there is NO way to grant *one-time* authorization to an app based on its bundle ID and then keep it authorized no matter how it changes (e.g., through updates).**

You have two options:

- Either: **Re-authorize** the application **every time you update** it.

  - After updating your app, go to `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility` and **toggle the checkmark** next to the list item representing your application (if you application isn't there, *drag* it there).
  - Note: With Apple's workaround in place - which for security reasons is NOT a good idea unless you truly need to use `property` statements that persist their values - it may be sufficient to *re-sign* the application - haven't verified that.
- Or: Use a **workaround** - ***not recommended for security reasons***:

  - **Make your app an *unchanging wrapper* that loads the true script code *at runtime* from a location OUTSIDE the app bundle** - that way, the app stays the same and doesn't require re-authorization even if the script file loaded at runtime changes.
  - Example: Say your true script code - involving code requiring assistive access - is stored as `~/Desktop.test.scpt`; your wrapper application, once authorized, can then invoke that script with `run script file ((path to home folder as text) & "Desktop:test.scpt")`

---

I don't have a specific explanation, but a **recommendation**:

- **Do not use *properties* (e.g., `property FNAME : "Input.txt"`) in your AppleScript-based applications**: AppleScript *persists* these automatically (preserves their values between runs), but the feature is implemented awkwardly (the persisted values are written to the `*.scpt` file itself - this is what causes the repeated authorization problem) and flimsily (if you modify your application and save (the `*.scpt` file at the heart of the) application again, previously persistent values are *lost*).
- **If you stay away from properties, the problem with repeated authorization simply goes away** (unless you update your application). You can roll your own persistence, e.g., via AppleScript's support for `.plist` (property-list) files (see the `System Events` dictionary).

  - You also won't need the workaround described in the linked support article (http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5914), which is also a plus, given that the workaround is based on opening up a security hole.

---

As for your specific question:

- The `??` is the - unhelpful - representation of the `csreq` columnn value from the `TCC.db` database and is *not a problem per se*; OSX manages that column behind the scenes; it contains a fingerprint of sorts identifying the application in its specific current form (similar to an MD5 hash, though I have no idea what is actually being used), so as to be able to detect tampering later.
- However, **I suspect you may be looking at the wrong database entry**:

  - I'm puzzled by your bundle ID being `com.atonus.open-cubase`: if your app is an AppleScript-based `*.app` bundle, its bundle ID would have the fixed prefix `com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.`, e.g., `com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.open-cubase`. Did you manually modify the bundle ID via the bundle's `Info.plist` file, or am I missing something?
  - When the OS determines tampering/a change in an authorized application:

    - It resets the `allowed` column value to `0`, i.e., revokes authorization
    - It resets the `csreq` column value to `NULL`.
  - Thus, **after you've seen the `... is not allowed assistive access` dialog, the database entry should be reported as `kTCCServiceAccessibility|com.atonus.open-cubase|0|0|1|`** - note the changed Boolean flags and the absence of the `??` at the end.

Comment: My answer is quite long so I'll write it as a bigger answer below.

Comment: @atonus: I saw an earlier version of your comment where you asked what I meant by 'persistent properties' - see my update for clarification.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've actually not used `property` definitions. I started to use my own ID `com.atonus.open-cubase` cause it seemed that the application name gets cached somewhere. This `open cubase` application was originally called `open cubase + osc` and when I renamed it to `open cubase` it still showed me the original name when I ran it. It wasn't really a problem, but now I think this current situation is somehow related to that.

Comment: How did you rename it? Renaming the bundle folder (`*.app`) is not enough. To ensure that the application name and bundle ID are changed too, you need to use `File > Duplicate` from AppleScript Editor. I would start from scratch: create a new document in AppleScript Editor, paste the script from your old app, save the new document as the app, authorize it, then see if the problem persists.

Comment: When I save AppleScript as an application I can add my own ID in **`Bundle Contents`** leaf element. I think the problem really began when I made a new script as you said and saved the old content to that. I renamed the old script to something like `open cubase old` and saved the new one with `open cubase`. Now it seems that OSX has mixed the old and the new somehow and I don't know how to just clear it out for it other way than making yet another new script and naming it like `launch cubase`, so that it's a new name also. But now I can't use name `open cubase` anymore.

Comment: To _rebuild_ your Launch Services database, run `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user` in Terminal - see if that helps; to _inspect_ it, run `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -dump`.

Comment: I feel like getting just deeper in the mud here.. Now I copied the script to a new applescript, didn't change anything with the ID, save it as an application, authorize with that Apple thing.. but now it still says that **`... is not allowed assistive access`** and the application does not appear to the privacy list anymore. So I can't give the access to it.

Comment: oh! but now I changed the ID of that file back to `com.atonus.open-cubase` and it appears to the privacy list. And I can grant access to it.

Comment: You can make any app appear in that list by _dragging_ it there.

Comment: ...but now I'm again to square one. Application is listed in the privacy list, access granted, but it still gives me **`... is not allowed assistive access`**.. huoh..

Comment: _Dragging_ won't make it appear in the list either.

Comment: Remove it from the list, then try dragging and checking; to remove, run from Terminal: `sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db "delete from access where client LIKE 'com.atonus.open-cubase';"`

Comment: Ok, now I managed to erase the `com.atonus.open-cubase` from Tcc.db. Then I _drag_ it again in the list and it appears there. When I run it, it says yet again **`... is not allowed assistive access`** but now if I check the Tcc.db I can see two listings appeared: **`kTCCServiceAccessibility|com.atonus.open-cubase|0|0|1|`** and **`kTCCServiceAccessibility|com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.open-cubase|0|1|1|`**

Comment: `0|0|1` means NOT authorized - normally, simply checking (activating the check mark) next to that entry in the list then grants authorization. `0|1|1` means that the entry IS authorized (2nd `1`,  though the last `1` is normally `0` when `??` follows).

Comment: Also: Are you saying that dragging a _single_ app resulted in *2* entries? That suggests that something is off.

Comment: No, dragging the application creates this: **`kTCCServiceAccessibility|com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.open-cubase|0|1|1|`** and running it creates this: **`kTCCServiceAccessibility|com.atonus.open-cubase|0|0|1|`**

Comment: This suggests that the app is internally inconsistent. Remove both entries, recreate your app _without_ trying to change its bundle ID (save the script code, delete the existing app, rebuild the launch services database, create the app anew with the saved script code), drag again.

Comment: Ok. Now it doesn't create **`com.atonus.open-cubase`** anymore when running it. There's **`com.apple.ScriptEditor.id.open-cubase`** in the Tcc.db, and application has access. But still it gives me **`... is not allowed assistive access`**

Comment: Ok, weirdness goes on. If I uncheck (deny access) for **`open cubase`** and then again run the new application, surprisingly **`com.atonus.open-cubase`** appears to Tcc.db. That ID should have been disappeared when I've emptied trash, but it came back from the dead..

Comment: Try creating a new app from scratch with a different name and bundle ID. Also, be sure that your app doesn't modify its bundle at runtime.

Comment: I created a new script, copied the content, save it with new name **`1093 open cubase`**, sign it with the apple thing, run, give access when prompted **`... is not allowed assistive access`**, run it again and it runs! Yes. But then I make one small change in the script, like change the variable name. Save it and run.. but then I'm again in square one. It says **`... is not allowed assistive access`** and the app is listed with granted access. Do I really need to make a completely new applescript when I make any changes?!

Comment: You shouldn't have to make a new application, but you DO need to re-authorize after every update - see my updated answer; hope that helps.

Comment: But even if I uncheck and check (re-authorize) again the application, it keeps giving that "not allowed"-dialog. Or do you mean signing it again? Cause if I try that, it returns a message that the application is already signed.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but I suggest you _get rid of the Apple workaround_: delete the downloaded `.plist` file, recreate your app _unsigned_. Then see if toggling the checkmark after an update fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @mklement0! Do you know if there's any way to see like a list of what applications I have signed with that Apple workaround?

Comment: Use the following shell command to list the paths of ad-hoc signed applications (looks in `/Applications` - adjust to your needs): `for a in /Applications/*.app/; do codesign -d --verbose=4 "$a" 2>&1 | egrep -q '^Signature=adhoc' && echo "$a"; done`. Ad-hoc signatures are those created with `codesign -s -`, as used in the workaround. However, your app should work once authorized, whether ad-hoc signed or not.

Comment: Well, I think I continue re-authorizing the application when I make changes. It's eventually the easiest way keep things organized: one file for one application.